# How to add a new route to the existing Flask app

Tags: python, flask, custom-error-pages

I am newbie with Flask and trying to add a new route to [Lama Clearner](https://github.com/Sanster/lama-cleaner/blob/0b3a9a68a296a3c4fc993bd904b7df6792c34579/lama_cleaner/server.py).

Existing routes work perfectly in my localhost but I added the below code

```
@app.route("/get_ping")
def get_ping():
    return str(True), 200
```

But when I try to make the request with http://localhost:8080/get_ping, I get 404 error. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are missing the port that the server is listening on in your request URL

Comment: Requesting `http://localhost:5000/get_ping,` for the Flask development server should work

Comment: Sorry but I forgot to add the port here, normally I had it but still no luck!

Comment: Where did you add the code? Make sure that part is actually run and that app is the same app as the server is actually listening on

Answer (score 0):

Your flask app is used another port to run. You must register app port in `app.run`. Ex:

```
app.run(
        host='0.0.0.0',
        threaded=True,
        port=8080,
        use_reloader=False,
    )
```